# Dis-Allowed Participation?

Tags: support

After deleting a 'Post', I was disallowed participation in providing answers in response to Questions. 
How do I regain my credibility, if I am not allowed to post?

Answer (score 3):

To give you some specific advice in addition to Dr. Mayhem's post:

- A lot of your posts have random errors like many extra apostrophes and capital letters.  You should correct all of those typographical issues.
- Many of your answers are speculative or wrong.  Make sure only to answer when you have good knowledge of the subject.
- Many of your answers are tangential to the question.  Make sure to only provide direct answers.

Comment: No Thanks ! I have found another 'Site, that is more 'User friendly.

Answer (score 2):

This is never because of one action - question bans kick in after a few negative behaviours.

We have a [post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/154443) that will explain it all to you, and help you understand how to reverse this.

The core section from that post is:

**How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?**

Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.**

Moderators cannot lift the ban.

**Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**

Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.

If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high priority.